# LAST INSERT ID SQL Subquery returns more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the below Stored Procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spCashDonation$$
  CREATE PROCEDURE spCashDonation(IN fname varchar(50),IN lname varchar(50),IN telNo bigint, IN pmode tinyint,IN amt decimal(8,2), OUT rno varchar(20))
    BEGIN
    Set @rmain := (select trim(concat('DNB', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%m'))));

  IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) = 1)) THEN
    Set @rpart = 1;
 END IF;

 IF ((trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 01) OR (trim(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%m')) != 1)) THEN
  Set @rpart := (select coalesce(max(ReceiptPart),0) from Donation) + 1;
 END IF;

 INSERT INTO Donation (ReceiptMain, ReceiptPart, firstName, lastName, telNo, payMode, Amount) VALUES (@rmain, @rpart, fname, lname, telNo, pmode, amt);

 Set @lid := (select LAST_INSERT_ID()from donation);
 select concat(ReceiptMain,ReceiptPart) into rno from donation where id = @lid;

 END$$
 DELIMITER ;

Call spCashDonation ('RAJIV','IYER',7506033048,0,1000,@rno);
select @rno;
```

When the table has no record, the first insert goes through fine. The upon the second insert it throws an error as

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

When I query for the last insert id, I get more than 1 value. So, I modified the last part of the procedure to:

> Set @lid := (select max(LAST_INSERT_ID()) from donation);

Please advice, if this is fine as it should not hinder any concurrent inserts and future CRUD operations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set @lid := (select LAST_INSERT_ID() from donation);
```

In the above line remove the `FROM` statement. If more than one record in the Donation table it will return the same number of times the [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) value.

So simply use `Set @lid := (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());` it will work in your case.